# Can't restart scan after disposing of the first connection

Tags: android, rx-android, rxandroidble

I have a rather long chain of Rx operations for my initial scan, connection and authorization. Here's the code.

```
fun startScanning() {
    getScanObservable()
            .take(1)
            .map { scanResult ->
                rxBleDevice = scanResult.bleDevice
                observeDeviceState()
                scanResult.bleDevice.establishConnection(false)
            }
            .flatMap { it }
            .map { bleConnection ->
                rxBleConnection = bleConnection
                bleConnection.discoverServices()
            }
            .flatMapSingle { it }
            .map { services ->
                rxBleDeviceServices = services
                performAuthentication()
            }
            .flatMap { it }
            .subscribe({
                state.postValue(State.AUTHENTICATED)
                setupNotifications()
            }, {
                FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().recordException(it)
            })
            .let { disposables.add(it) }
}
```

So, to sum this up, the code takes the first scan result and immediately starts establishing connection. Once that's done, I discover services and then finally authenticate the mobile client. At the end of the "chain" (in the subscribe callback), I set up all of the needed characteristic notifications and then save the `Disposable` into my `CompositeDisposable` variable which also consists of all the Disposables that I get from subscribing to characteristic notifications.

When I call `disposables.dispose()`, the client does in fact get disconnected. I know it because the peripheral shows disconnected status and `RxBleDevice` shows `Disconnected` status as well.

The problem is if I call the `startScanning` method again, nothing happens. The first `map` operation is never called and none of the subscribe methods are called as well. It only works if I restart the activity, which re-instantiates everything from scratch.

Here's also the `getScanObservable()` code:

```
private fun getScanObservable(): Observable<ScanResult> {
    val scanSettings = ScanSettings.Builder()
            .setScanMode(ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_LOW_LATENCY)
            .setCallbackType(ScanSettings.CALLBACK_TYPE_ALL_MATCHES)
            .build()
    val scanFilter = ScanFilter.Builder()
            .setDeviceName(token.deviceUid)
            .build()
    return rxBleClient.scanBleDevices(scanSettings, scanFilter)
}
```

Here's how I dispose:

```
private val disposables = CompositeDisposable()

fun cleanup() {
    if (!disposables.isDisposed) {
        disposables.dispose()
        rxBleDevice = null
        rxBleDeviceServices = null
        rxBleConnection = null
    }
}
```

I call the `cleanup()` method whenever I want to close the connection and prepare the device to rescan and reconnect. That's why I also destroy all of the RxAndroidBle references and only keep the RxBleClient reference.

Comment: Do you have, perhaps, an `nRF Connect` app opened at the same time in the background? And show how your `getScanObservable()` works

Comment: @DariuszSeweryn I don't think I have any other apps opened that might be using BT. This is my development device and I don't run anything else on it other than my apps.

I've added the `getScanObservable` code as well.

Comment: Is it a dual-mode peripheral?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by dual-mode peripheral, as I'm relatively new to bluetooth. I've tested the connection with two clients now (my iOS as well as Android client). When I dispose of the disposable on Android, my peripheral beeps like it should when it's disconnected. iOS will then connect without a problem while Android won't start scanning again until the app is restarted. Even creating a new instance of RxBleClient does not help, which makes me assume that there's something weird going on with background bluetooth logic. Maybe the device never stops scanning, but it should have.

Comment: What phone/OS you test on?

Comment: It's a Pixel 4, Android 10. I've also just tried keeping a reference to RxBleDevice, so I could skip scanning the second time and go straight for the `establishConnection` call. But that doesn't work as well. When I try to re-establish connection, the RxBleClient state goes from `Disconnected` to `Connecting` and then straight back to `Disconnected`, so it seems like it just doesn't want to reconnect at all, until app or activity is restarted.

Comment: Didn't Android 10 add permissions for background Bluetooth usage?

Comment: Android 10 does need location permission for bluetooth to work, but nothing else that I would be aware of. Besides, I'm not doing anything in background here, so I'm not sure if that's even relevant.

Comment: I think it's also worth noting that it seems like I'm able to scan & connect again if I lose connection by walking away from the BT device until it loses connection. It's only when I manually dispose of my connection and then try to scan again that it doesn't work.

Comment: How do you dispose it? What is `disposables`?

Comment: I've added the code above. Basically I use the `CompositeDisposable` to collect all of the RxBle related disposables (the one I get from startScanning and the ones I get when registering notifications, so I can dispose of everything at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you cannot start a new scan lays in how you dispose the previous one. If you would look into the implementation or `CompositeDisposable.add()` Javadoc you would see that:

> ```
> /**
> * Adds a disposable to this container or disposes it if the
> * container has been disposed.
> * @param disposable the disposable to add, not null
> * @return true if successful, false if this container has been disposed
> * @throws NullPointerException if {@code disposable} is null
> */
> ```

You call `CompositeDisposable.dispose()` therefore disposing the container. If you would add an `.doOnDispose { Log.i("startScanning", "disposed!") }` to the `startScanning()` function you would quickly discovered that.

If you want to dispose contents of `CompositeDisposable` but not the container use `CompositeDisposable.clear()`:

> ```
> /**
>  * Atomically clears the container, then disposes all the previously contained Disposables.
>  */
> ```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this was the problem. I am new to Rx as well as Bluetooth, so implementing this is a huge challenge, but I'm getting there!